# restricting IP security

Tags: security, iis, windows-server-2012, ip-restrictions

Having an issue with restricting IP security.
I have made a web.config file and placed it in the folder I am trying to restrict see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" enableProxyMode="true" denyAction="Forbidden">            
        <clear />           
        <add ipAddress="123.456.789" allowed="true" />
    </ipSecurity>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have also adjusted the applicationHost.config to:

```
    <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

However when browsing to a file in that folder I get a 403.
I have restarted IIS and IP address is correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: What IP address you are seeing in the IIS logs ? Do you see 123.456.789 ?  And isince proxymode is enabled what is there in x-forwaded header.

Comment: Thanks Ravi
Log files showed a different IP address (987.654.321) than I get using whatmyip (123.456.789).

With the enabledProxyMode="true" it requires both IPs in the config to allow access.

I assume this is to do with a proxy address IIS see before my static IP?

Comment: Usually that shouldn't be the case.What kind of network you are in ? Usually office networks will have lot of switches across so you won't be able to predict your IP. Another situation is if your request routed through a proxy before reaching IIS.

Comment: Yes it is an office network.
I think as you said the request is been routed through a proxy first.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Great! I will post it as answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the client IP (c-ip) in IIS logs and add that to ip - restrictions rules.